# How to accept ASP.NET web API controller file for HttpClient in Xamarin Forms PCL application

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have a webapi in asp.net i have a localhost address like `http://localhost:50908/api/Schools/` This gives an output in XML file which is something like this:

```
   <ArrayOfSchool xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MasterDetail.Models">
<School>
<SchoolCode>TDSB001</SchoolCode>
<SchoolId>1</SchoolId>
<SchoolName>Claude Watson School for Arts</SchoolName>
</School>
<School>
<SchoolCode>TDSB002</SchoolCode>
<SchoolId>2</SchoolId>
<SchoolName>Harvest Community School of Arts.</SchoolName>
</School>
<School>
<SchoolCode>TDSB003</SchoolCode>
<SchoolId>3</SchoolId>
<SchoolName>Yogin Bhatt Arts School.</SchoolName>
</School>
</ArrayOfSchool>
```

My code for client:

```
 public async Task<List<School>> GetAsync()

        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://10.115.160.142/sampleSchools.xml");
            string response = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();//Getting response 
            response.Replace(((char)0xFEFF).ToString(), "");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://10.115.160.142/sampleSchools.xml");
            List<School> SchoolDetailsList = new List<School>();

            //  await DisplayAlert("XmlParsing", doc.ToString, "Ok");
            foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("School"))
            {
                School schoolItem = new School();
                schoolItem.SchoolCode = item.Element("SchoolCode").Value.ToString();
                schoolItem.SchoolId = item.Element("SchoolId").Value.ToString();
                schoolItem.SchoolName = item.Element("SchoolName").Value.ToString();
                SchoolDetailsList.Add(schoolItem);

            }
            //Binding listview with server response  
            var ResList = SchoolDetailsList;


            return ResList;
        }
```

The like i have given above is not working for my URI, so i made a copy of the xml file and put it on xampp server. That way it is working but that is not the proper way. How to do this operation?

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What specifically is happening?  What errors or exceptions are you getting?  Have you identified which specific line causes the problem?

Comment: Sir i am really sorry about that , So i added break point at my http client when it gets response. so when i use this URI " http://localhost:50908/api/Schools/"  it gives me a null value, But , When u put the xml file which i am using through xampp server it gives me a perfect output in a list.

Comment: do NOT use localhost, use the IP or FQDN of your server

Comment: Can you give me an idea how to access it using my ip adress instead local if my ip adress looks somthing like this 132.168.14.12 for  "http://localhost:50908/api/Schools/" this??

Comment: simply replace the hostname with the IP.  You should also be sure whatever local server you're using allows remote requests, and that your firewall isn't blocking anything

Comment: It is not getting connected Sir , is IIS Express making a trouble here you think so?

Comment: So, I found a solution for this question! Please let me know fellas if anyone has the same question.

Comment: if you were able to solve the problem yourself, then you should post it as an answer to your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always try change it to iis server instead iisexpress to run this kind of code